# How to pickle inherited exceptions?

Tags: python, pickle

This code

```
import pickle
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Some error message")   

c = Error()    
a = pickle.dumps(c)
b = pickle.loads(a)
```

raises error:

```
...
    b = pickle.loads(a)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

However this code:

```
import pickle
class MyBaseException:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class Error(MyBaseException):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Some error message")

c = Error()
a = pickle.dumps(c)
b = pickle.loads(a)
```

works fine.

**Question:** How do I pickle objects inherited from Python base Exception object?

Python version: 3.6.3

Comment: Since you are dumping an object, have you tried `pickle.dump()` (not `pickle.dumps()`)

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan: that makes zero difference here. `dump()` writes the pickled data to a file, while `dumps()` returns the produced data to the caller.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan: and **everything** in Python is an object, so I'm not sure what you even mean by *since you are dumping an object*. How would you *not* dump an object?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan
Why should I use `pickle.dump()`? I'm not writing anything to file. I send pickled information through socket to other machine and then unpickle it.

Comment: @SergeyDylda: you can safely ignore that comment, it makes zero sense.

Comment: Just add `*args` to `__init__`. There's no need to re-define `__reduce__`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BaseException` implements a [`__reduce__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) that returns a tuple with the type and the value of `self.args` (a third value is included if there are more attributes besides `.args`):

```
>>> Error().__reduce__()
(<class '__main__.Error'>, ('Some error message',))
```

This tuple is pickled and when unpickling, used to re-create the instance. The class also implements [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__), which would be called if there was a third element in the `__reduce__` return tuple, but that's not relevant here.

You'd have to provide a different implementation of `__reduce__`:

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Some error message")
    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), ()
```